# import numpy into flask app

Tags: python, flask

I'm was trying to run my python code on a web server and found out i have to use flask or django so I decided to use flask and after reading some articles i wrote a hello world script and it ran but when i tried do more complex things like import numpy and pandas I kept giving me internal server errors and I have googled it but haven't got what I wanted. Please is this possible with flask or is there a better way to run my script online and am still a new to this. Thank you in advance. This is the script am trying to run

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
  file = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')

  print('man')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

This is the logs

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 man
 [2017-03-12 22:12:06,757] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_
 request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
 ValueError: View function did not return a response
 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2017 22:12:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Comment: The error is not ought due to the `numpy` import but due to the fact that your `hello` view does not return anything (as you can see from the traceback)! After `print('man')` write something like this: `return 'It worked'` (each `view` function *must always return a response*).

Comment: @nik_m thank you very much. Just edited the code and it worked flawlessly, you just saved me a ton of development time

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted an answer also below with a little more details.

Comment: and I will make sure to keep the info about the view in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not ought due to the `numpy` import but due to the fact that your `hello` view does not return anything (as you can see from the traceback).

```
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

The view just stores `movies.csv` in a variable. Nothing more. The client awaits for a response which never gets.

Try, after the `print('man')` statement to write something like this:

`return 'It worked'`

Remember: each view function handles a request and **must always return a response (whether its a 404 error, a text, an HTML page or something else)**.